# JavaScript escape array of array

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I need to send a post request and then return data like this format

```
return 
[
  ['title', 'dau', 'rate']
  ['title1', 'value1', 'value1-1'],
  ['title2', 'value2', 'value2-1'],
  ['title3', 'value3', 'value2-1'],
  ['title4', 'value4', 'value2-1'],
]
```

Now I've written this

```
makeCsvData = (responseData) => {
  const dailyData = responseData.map(day => (
    [
      day[0], //title
      day[1].new_group_owners || 0, //value1
      day[1].wek_stay_rate || 0, //value2
    ])
  )

  return dailyData
}
```

Then how do I make my data? I've written this, but it's not correct

```
return 
[
  ['title', 'dau', 'rate'],
  dailyData,
]
```

Comment: Return from where exactly?

Comment: The title of the question doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: I am not sure how to explain that, but @FelixKling give the answer which I need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Array#concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat):

```
return [['title', 'dau', 'rate']].concat(dailyData);
```

or a [*spread element*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator#Spread_in_array_literals):

```
return [['title', 'dau', 'rate'], ...dailyData];
```

You could also use `Array#forEach` or `Arra#reduce` instead of `Array#map` to push to an existing array.

Comment: Thanks, that has been great help